# What to look out for when buying your first vintage camera

Tags: slr, vintage

I'm very new at the topic of photography.

I'm looking for a vintage SLR or Range Finder camera that takes films that can be easily/cheaply bought. At the same time I would like the size of the image to be the biggest possible as we are looking to print large images so I'm not looking for instant cameras.

I would like to be able to control at least shutter speed and exposure.

How can I tackle this selection process?

Comment: I assume this question is getting downvotes because it is asking for a specific product recommendation, but I chose to read it slightly differently, and I think it can also be easily rephrased into a valid, more useful question for here, namely: what to look out for when buying your first vintage camera.

Comment: Questions that ask for "best camera", whether vintage or otherwise, tend to attract people showing up to cheer for their particular favorite, which _can_ make an interesting list in theory (but in practice usually makes a really random and spotty one). So, any rephrase should avoid that, please.

Comment: Yea. There is no way of knowing which is the "best". Also the specifications are too "imaginative". I have the feeling you do not know much about photo. What are you concerned about 1) Camera for learning 2) Camera for actually use it  3) Cost benefit for you or for the person you are buying it for? Probably a digital compact camera will be a better gift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael Clark writes, the general answer is "it depends". As you intend to use the camera, rather than collect it, here's a few more pointers that might be helpful.

First of all, here are some factors (in no particular order) that I would consider when buying a vintage camera:

- **reliability**: some cameras are more reliable than others, for some models, you will find a large number of cameras in good working conditions even decades after their production was stopped, for others, there may be many known problems and defects and you will not easily find a camera in good working condition and it's often best to stay away from these, as they're ticking bombs (typical problems include the deterioration of materials such as glue, plastics, or weak mechanical parts, all of which are usually very hard to impossible to fix)
- **availability of ...**: there's no use in buying a camera, if it is hard to get lenses, films, or batteries for it, so I would at least buy a body that comes with a lens, uses some common film format, and does work with modern batteries (or can easily be converted to work with modern batteries)
- **condition**: most vintage cameras will show some sign of use, and that's fine, but if there are large dents, crumbly or rusty bits, dirt, or any other bigger signs of wear, I would be careful.
- **convenience**: in particular, if this is your first vintage camera, you might not want to wander away too far from the look & feel of modern cameras. So, you might want to look at things like: Does it have a built-in exposure meter? How easily can you figure out its basic operations (setting shutter speed and exposure)? And so on... It's fun to have a vintage camera with all kinds of weird buttons, but if you have to figure out what they do without a manual, this might become frustrating very quickly (or even worse, you may actually damage the camera, as may happen with some vintage Russian rangefinders...)

With these things in mind, here's how I then would proceed.

- First, go to your local used camera shop, browse some local classified ads, or use whatever you prefer in the web (eBay, KEH camera, etc.). Browse around and have a look at cameras in your price range, ask questions (if possible), and note down (as precisely as possible) those cameras you're most interested in.
- Then, go back home and use the internet to find out everything you can about these cameras (in particular also with respect to the factors I mentioned above).
- Also, check whether you can find a manual, http://www.butkus.org//chinon/index.html is a great source fort his.
- Finally, purchase whatever camera seems most suitable to your purposes.
- Also remember to ask your friends and family, there's quite a number of "Grandma's old camera" still lying around in the attics.
- Maybe also consider putting some money on the side for buying and processing the film.

*A note on shops*: Generally, shops will be slightly more expensive than eBay & Co. (even though, you will find that many vintage cameras on eBay are overpriced, hint: it's those that don't sell...), but there are also many advantages to buying at a local shop. They should be able to show you how the camera works (if they can't do that, it's probably best to walk away from that shop) and very often they should also give you some form of warranty. At least, they should be able to guarantee that the camera is in working condition and grant the right to return it if there's a problem within the first three months after purchase (or similar).

*A note on film*: As you want film to be easily available, you probably should go for [135 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/135_film) or [120 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120_film), these are the most common formats and are, comparatively, cheap. Larger formats are available, but will cost significantly more (and most likely, you also will not be able to find a camera in your suggested price range). For these films you can also typically still easily find a place that will process them.

Finally, in order to give a specific recommendation: I personally (and note, this is a highly personal view, there's many other excellent cameras) like the [Minolta SR-T series](http://www.rokkorfiles.com/SRT%20Series.htm) a lot and the [Minolta SR-T 101](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Minolta_SR-T_101) with a 50mm f/1.4 or f/1.7 lens is probably the vintage camera I use most often. This combo should be available in your price range (actually, quite a bit below it) and, in my opinion, fits the criteria listed above.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" always depends on use case and user preference. When talking about vintage equipment it is also dependent upon the condition/usability of the piece in question. So there's no universal right answer to your question, other than "It depends."

Comment: Also, what is "vintage"? To some people, any film camera is a vintage camera.

Comment: My father has a vintage Nikon D3000.....